# xsd.exe not generating code for all elements

Tags: visual-studio-2010, xsd.exe

I am trying to generate a strongly typed dataset for the schema defintion located at:

https://www.shpdata.com/xsd/CAHPSHospice.xsd

The file defines 5 top level elements, 4 simple (like xs:int, xs:string, etc) and one complex.

When the resulting class is generated it only contains properties for the complex type but the others are not present.

How can I get xsd to include these other elements?

Comment: Seems to work in VS2013 (xsd, Version=4.0.30319.33440).  Class `SHP_CAHPS_HOSPICE_DATA` contains properties for `VENDOR_ID`, `BATCH`, `TOTAL_BATCHES`, `BATCH_KEY_TIME_STAMP`, and array of `CAHPS_HOSPICE_SURVEY_DATA`.  Maybe the 2010 version (I assume is 3.5) has an issue?

Comment: Let me try real quick and get back to you, thanks!

Comment: I tried with that version and I am getting the same thing

Comment: Are you generating a dataset or class? If I gen a class it works.

Comment: Sorry, was doing class, misread the question.